# ASP.NET CustomValidator trying to match to System.EventHandler?

Tags: asp.net, customvalidator

I have markup so:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="Accountname" />
<asp:CustomValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="Accountname" OnServerValidate="Accountname_CheckUnique" meta:resourcekey="ACCOUNTNAME_UNAVAILABLE" />
```

Codebehind so:

```
protected void Accountname_CheckUnique(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs arguments)
{
    arguments.IsValid = Foo();     
}
```

Which *was* working just fine, and then without changing anything on the page ASP now insists:

> No overload for
>   'Accountname_CheckUnique' matches
>   delegate 'System.EventHandler'

Well no, and nor should it according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.customvalidator.aspx). It's late and I'm tired, anybody know how to fix this or point out the glaring flaw in my comprehension?

Edit:

I've also tried += binding as an eventhandler in the codebehind and it still requires the EventArgs signature. Makes. No. Sense.

Edit 2:

Deleted and recreated the page entirely (copy paste) and problem went away. Assume some niche thing created a very localised problem.

**@MODS: Please close.**

Comment: What happens if you change it to match what the compiler wants?  Something seems fishy.

Comment: The page compiles but the method is useless - '(arguments as ServerValidateEventArgs)' is null, so I can't use it for validation.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe remove "protected" from the Accountname_CheckUnique method definition?

Comment: No (and I did try anyway), you'd get a "foo does not contain a definition for 'Accountname_CheckUnique'" error if it was a scoping issue.

Comment: I'm a noob here, it would have been better if I entered this as a comment. Also should have checked your reputation before posting the obvious suggestion <grin>. Should I delete the answer so this goes back under "unanswered"?

Comment: No, it's helpful to have wrong answers because it's educational for future readers and it prevents other people posting the same. Any well intentioned answer is valuable, regardless of whether it also happens to be correct. (and rep is just a number, you'll get there)